# Encoding Dataframe features numerically

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I am having a dataframe, with a number of features. There is one particular feature, that is totally dynamic and I aim to encode it. I cannot use one-hot encoding as the unique count of values can change. LabelEncoder can be of use, but can the number of classes/target labels be changed ?

Consider an example (the **Name** feature):

```
index | A | B | Name
------+---+---+-----
  1     5   6    abc
  2     4   7    abc
  2     3   0    def
  2     3   0    ghi
  3     3   0    abc
  3     3   0    def
```

I wish to encode it as

```
index | A | B | Name
------+---+---+-----
  1     5   6    1
  2     4   7    1
  2     3   0    2
  2     3   0    3
  3     3   0    1
  3     3   0    2
```

And also keeping in mind that if later on another value different than all these comes up, they automatically get stored in the encoder by the next successive value like even if the next row input is

```
index | A | B | Name
------+---+---+-----
  1     5   6    xyz
```

It gets encoded to and is used as

```
index | A | B | Name
------+---+---+-----
  1     5   6    4
```

And how do I get the original value back ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `factorize`

```
df.Name=df.Name.factorize()[0]+1
```

Comment: But is this flexible to new values as I said might be a case ? And how do I get the original value back ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `astype` category and then use the category accessor `.cat` to get the assigned codes:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].astype('category').cat.codes + 1
```

Output:

```
   index  A  B  Name
0      1  5  6     1
1      2  4  7     1
2      2  3  0     2
3      2  3  0     3
4      3  3  0     1
5      3  3  0     2
```

Comment: But is this flexible to new values as I said might be a case ? And how do I get the original value back ?

Comment: Please create amost exhaustive example and test case.

Comment: I am sorry, please check out the edited post. I realised this later and added it

Comment: That is pretty confusing.... So you have an original dataframe with Name, you encode Name to generate a new dataframe.  You go back to the original dataframe insert a new name?  You can still encode that Name again.  Nothing is stopping you from doing this.

Comment: The issue is this is the data for the machine learning model that I am building. Now the xyz label or the new label can even come as a part of the testing data and can be unseen. That is why I cannot go back to the dataframe an insert it back

Comment: That is a data leakage issue.   You might need to use LabelEncoder from the sklearn library.